# The use of the empty set and the overall set of real numbers in proofs

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, multivariable-calculus

So I recently came across, for the first time in an analysis textbook, the use of the empty set being both open and closed to show the validity of an unambiguous statement about an arbitrary set. The same thing with the set of reals, and it being both open and closed, to show why the statement is true. So here are some examples, by the way, I will not post the entire proof unless necessary. So my question is, why and when should we use these tools regarding the empty set and $\mathbb{R}^n$ being both open and closed? It does make sense why most analysis texts bring this problem up and prove it is so.

Theorem-$E$ is closed iff $E$ contains all its limit points

Pf-...Suppose $E\neq\emptyset$ which contains all its limit points. If E is not closed $\implies E\neq\mathbb{R}^n$ and by definition $E^c\neq\emptyset$ and not open...

Theorem-$f$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(V)$ is relatively open in $E$ for every $V$ open in $\mathbb{R}^m$

Pf-...Since $\emptyset$ is open, we may suppose that some $\vec{a}\in f^{-1}(V)$...

Let me know if more details are needed, I posted proof I have in my notes. The book has it more concise

Comment: The whole space and the empty set are always clopen (Closed and open) in any topology.  One nice use of them is that they form a top and bottom element in the partial ordering of all open (or closed) sets under the subset order.  which can let you make use of Zorn's lemma

Comment: Side-Note: "Sets are not doors." - John Hunter